# How to add <Bold></Bold> text to the content of a TextBlock in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to create this programmatically:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource WordStyle}" x:Name="Foo"><Bold>d</Bold>o o<Bold>dd</Bold></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. To add bold text, italic text and line breaks or change the foreground color or font family using C#, the `TextBlock.Inlines` property works perfectly.

```
Foo.Inlines.Clear();

// Bold text.
var block = new Run();
block.Text = "d";
block.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Foo.Inlines.Add(block);

// Regular text.
block = new Run();
block.Text = "o o";
Foo.Inlines.Add(block);

// Bold and italics text.
block = new Run();
block.FontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
block.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
block.Text = "dd";
Foo.Inlines.Add(block);
```